# Raw Mysql query working on phpMyAdmin returning error in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have this Eloquent query:

```
return DB::table('users')
        ->leftJoin('bet', function($join) use ($competition_id){
          $join->on('users.id', '=', 'bet.user_id');
          $join->on('bet.competition_id','=', DB::raw("$competition_id"));
        })
        ->select('users.*', DB::raw('SUM(points) as score'))->get();
```

it returns me an error:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause (SQL: **select `users`.*, SUM(points) as score from `users` left join `bet` on `users`.`id` = `bet`.`user_id` and `bet`.`competition_id` = 1**)

if I just copy-paste the generated SQL (in bold) in PhpMyAdmin, it works perfectly...

Could you please help me solving this issue? because it makes no sense to me...

Thank you

**SOLUTION**

The problem was just the missing group by:

```
return DB::table('users')
    ->leftJoin('bet', function($join) use ($competition_id){
      $join->on('users.id', '=', 'bet.user_id');
      $join->on('bet.competition_id','=', DB::raw("$competition_id"));
    })
    ->select('users.*', DB::raw('SUM(points) as score'))->groupBy('users.id')->get();
```

**SOLUTION #2**

Depending on the version or configuration of MySQL, the solution above is not working and I had to groupBy all the fields as advised by Eric:

```
return DB::table('users')
    ->leftJoin('bet', function ($join) use ($competition_id) {
        $join->on('users.id', '=', 'bet.user_id');
        $join->on('bet.competition_id', '=', DB::raw("$competition_id"));
    })
    ->select('users.*', DB::raw('SUM(points) as score'))
    ->groupBy('users.id')
    ->groupBy('users.name')
    ->groupBy('users.firstName')
    ->groupBy('users.lastName')
    ->groupBy('users.email')
    ->groupBy('users.admin')
    ->groupBy('users.password')
    ->groupBy('users.remember_token')
    ->groupBy('users.created_at')
    ->groupBy('users.updated_at')->get();
}
```

Comment: mysql I assume?

Comment: Your laravel is probably using strict mode, while the servers default isn't. You probably need to add `->groupBy('users.id)`.

Comment: You have `SUM()`, but I don't see any `GROUP BY` in your statement.

Comment: Put all non-aggregated columns in `GROUP BY`.  Your query won't even run in all dbms, except for maybe `MySQL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have many questions but 4. is the cause of it

1. Why aren't you using the ORM? You should take advantage of the framework whenever possible
2. Why DB::raw on $competition_id? it's just a value you're inserting into the query
3. You can use selectRaw on your final select to avoid another DB::raw
4. It is most likely the lack of a groupBy (your sum is at fault). You can do this by placing a `group by` or disabling strict mode on MySql

Try this:

```
return DB::table('users')
        ->leftJoin('bet', function($join) use ($competition_id){
          $join->on('users.id', '=', 'bet.user_id');
          $join->on('bet.competition_id','=', DB::raw("$competition_id"));
        })
        ->select('users.*', DB::raw('SUM(points) as score'))->groupBy('users.id')->get();
```

Comment: I use $competition_id in a raw request otherwise it seems to be considered as a column: (unknown column '1'). Your query is almost good, I just had to change a bit the select part to make it work (see my updated post). Thanks!

Comment: Glad you got it to work! If you disable strict mode, you won't need groupBy (although you should). This is because: If you are going to sum a column, mysql needs to know what is it based on :) Feel free to classify this answer as a solution or provide the solution for future users

Comment: What is funny with this request is that depending on which computer i'm developing my app, it is still not working as is. I think it's related to the version and/or configuration of MySQL. See my updated answer to have the other solution. Thanks again!